# なかなか Translation

Tags: translation

I have the following to translate.

```
東京に行ったことがある友達の話では、
東京都内では、
外国人がタクシーを止めるのは、とてもむずかしいそうで、
なかなか止まらないそうです。
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
In a conversation with my friend who has been to Tokyo
in the inside of the Tokyo metropolitan area
I hear that a foreigner stopping a taxi is very difficult and
I hear that ... won't stop.
```

My questions are

1. Why is the `そうです` structure used twice (last 2 lines)?
2. What is `なかなか`?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: Google said "quite".

Comment: Allow me to rephrase: have you tried a real dictionary?

Comment: LOL. Nope. Sadly don't have one.

Comment: Also found "rather" online. They "rather not stop" perhaps. Because foreigners suck? Hehe

Comment: えっ？辞書なしで日本語勉強してるの？なかなかいないよ、そういう人・・・

Comment: `Sadly I don't have one`.  There are tons listed in our [meta resources](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/761/78) topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. そう =  I hear that～
   Usage: plain form: V、い－adj、な－adj、Ｎ＋そうだ
   In Japanese そう is 2 using. Other, meaning is It looks ～，It seems ～
   くindicates the speaker’s conjecture or judgement based on what he/she sees or feels>
2. なかなか = very, considerably, by no means (with negative verb)